# Cannot deploy Google App due to errors

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, eclipse-plugin, java-7

I have created a simple application using the Google App Engine

**Environment**

- Eclipse 4.2 (Juno) Plugin - http://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/4.2
- JDK 7

I was able to create a sample application and run it **locally**.

When I try to **deploy** it gives me an error

**Error in eclipse**

Deploying 'applicationname' to Google has encountered a problem.
Unable to update app: The application contains Java 7 classes, but the --use_java7 flag has not been set.

See the deployment console for more details
Unable to update app: The application contains Java 7 classes, but the --use_java7 flag has not been set.

**The logs show**

Unable to update:
java.lang.RuntimeException: The application contains Java 7 classes, but the --use_java7 flag has not been set.
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.Application.createStagingDirectory(Application.java:576)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppAdminImpl.doUpdate(AppAdminImpl.java:370)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppAdminImpl.update(AppAdminImpl.java:53)
    at com.google.appengine.eclipse.core.proxy.AppEngineBridgeImpl.deploy(AppEngineBridgeImpl.java:433)
    at com.google.appengine.eclipse.core.deploy.DeployProjectJob.runInWorkspace(DeployProjectJob.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(InternalWorkspaceJob.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)

I see someone has encountered the same error before

[Failed to deploy to Google App Engine because --use_java7 flag has not been set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13848495/failed-to-deploy-to-google-app-engine-because-use-java7-flag-has-not-been-set)

I installed JDK 6 but I could not get the application to work either.

What are my alternatives to getting the application to work? - some thoughts...

- **Use prior version of plug in?**
- **Install JDK 6 by itself?**
- **Some other options?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use JDK 6.

[Similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12587432/updating-play-app-from-jdk-6-to-7-on-gae)

[Java Overview Docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/overview)

> App Engine runs Java applications using the Java 6 virtual machine (JVM). The App Engine SDK supports Java 5 and later, and the Java 6 JVM can use classes compiled with any version of the Java compiler up to Java 6.

Comment: Thanks - I will try that and let you know